# Book set in Victorian-era London involving a society of unmarried women who kill people

Tags: story-identification, novel

Admittedly, I don't remember much. I read maybe the first chapter of the book, years ago. I'm not even sure if it's part of a series or a standalone, but if someone can find it, it's you people.

It's written from a POV of a young lady, living in London. She attended some kind of institution for young ladies (?), but my impression is that it's for impoverished noblewomen, perhaps for educating governesses.
There's a story about her roommate there; her name was maybe Lucy? And I dimly remember that she hated it.

Now she is in some kind of society with other unmarried women, and she casually mentions that they kill people. Perhaps masquerading as governesses?

It had a Victorian feel, and the character and her associates had a traumatic upbringing.

I think the cover was black and white, but I'm not sure.

And that's it. :(

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, does the story contain any science fiction or fantasy elements?

Comment: @LogicDictates caught me here. no idea if it's fantasy. it's just i usually read fantasy or sci fi, so if I started it it must be, but now i am not sure...

Comment: uhh between 2-7 years ago?

Comment: Whether or not a story involves sci-fi or fantasy elements determines whether or not it's on-topic here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP cannot confirm that the book being asked about here includes any sci-fi or fantasy elements.

Comment: I wonder if it's a book in [The Finishing School Series](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheFinishingSchoolSeries)? Disclaimer: I have only read the TV Tropes page, not any of the actual books in that series.

Comment: If it is from that series, then it would have fantasy/Alternate History elements.

Comment: If it's the Carriger series the heroine is *Sophronia* and her room mate is *Dimity*. @user159654 does this ring any bells? If it is this series it's definitely fantasy as it features vampires, werewolves and ghosts.

Comment: From the TV Tropes page: *"At the end, Sophronia becomes Alexia Tarabotti's governess as her latest assignment, nodding to a mention in Blameless about a really fantastic governess she used to have as a child."* Though some sources, such as the series' fandom.com site, say "nanny" instead of "governess". And @JohnRennie it does sound like the roommate wouldn't have liked it as much as the main character - she is apparently an example of the "Minion with an F in Evil" trope.

Comment: As for the cover being black and white... the backgrounds are in colour, but the foreground of each book in the series is a B&W picture of one of the characters - albeit holding a coloured object. I think all the books are written in third person, so not sure how well this matches "from a POV of a young lady".

Comment: @AJM we'll just have to wait and see if the OP gets back to us.